# Angularjs typeahead display array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to have a typeahead with an array of objects? 
[Example of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4PVz.png)

Edit: My current code only filters through the name object, and i want it to be able to filter through all the object such that, when i enter the postal code into the searchbox, it will display both the name and postal

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="cname for cname in all | filter:$viewValue:onlyMatch| limitTo:5">
```

The example would be like this :
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnoD9.png)

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it as

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.NAME for state in POSTALCODES | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MzHjz0oSaLxTkzy15jR3?p=preview)**

Comment: I got this error Error: Expected typeahead specification

Comment: Is it possible to display both the postal code and name in the typeahead?